# Test the entire method with async, querySelectorAll, focus

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

How to test the entire method `onShowSidebar`?

```
   public async onShowSidebar() {
        await delay();

        const inputList = this.elem.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('#form input, #form textarea') as NodeListOf<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>;
        const selected = Array.from(inputList).find(f => !f.disabled);
        if (selected)
            selected.focus();
    }

constructor(
    private elem: ElementRef
) { }

delay = (ms: number = 100): Promise<boolean> => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(true);
    }, ms);
  });
};
```

My difficulty is in making a mock of the querySelectorAll to return elements. And then test whether the focus was called.

Note: querySelectorAll needs to be used because custom input components are used, simple exemple render like this:

```
<form id="form">
  <custom-input><input></custom-input>
  <custom-area><textarea></custom-area>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time trying to do an effective test:

```
it('test onShowSidebar input1 focus', async () => {
    const element = spyOn(component['elem'].nativeElement, 'querySelectorAll').and.callThrough();

    await component.onShowSidebar();

    expect(element).toHaveBeenCalled();

    const input1 = element.calls.first().returnValue[0] as HTMLInputElement; //in the following tests just increase the index
    const inputFocused = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector(`:focus`);

    expect(inputFocused).toBeTruthy();
    expect(inputFocused).toEqual(input1);
});

// disable the next input and do as many tests as needed and returnValue[1]

it('test onShowSidebar without focus', async () => {
    component.formGroup.get('input1').disable();
    component.formGroup.get('input2').disable();
    component.formGroup.get('input3').disable();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const element = spyOn(component['elem'].nativeElement, 'querySelectorAll').and.callThrough();

    await component.onShowSidebar();

    expect(element).toHaveBeenCalled();

    const inputs = element.calls.first().returnValue as Array<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>;
    const inputFocused = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector(`:focus`);

    expect(inputFocused).toBeFalsy();
    inputs.forEach(input => {
        expect(inputFocused).not.toEqual(input);
    });
});
```

Some important points:

1. it was necessary to use `component['elem']` instead of a mock of
   `ElementRef`
2. `callThrough` was used to make the real call and return the rendered
   elements
3. as the `element` was just a `HTMLInputElement` return and not a mock, it
   was not possible to test whether focus was called, so the solution
   was to check who is focused and if it is the same expected by the
   sequence of inputs on the screen